# Sending structured data over named pipe (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

i am using a named pipe for IPC on a Debian system. I will be sending some data as a set of strings from a bash script to a background running process written in C code.

The data i want to send is four strings eg accountid, firstname,surname, description. Currently i am sending the data as a char array separated by spaces from my bash script.

```
echo "accountid firstname surname description" >$pipe
```

In the background process i read the pipe data like this into char array 'datain'

```
res = read(pipe_fd, datain, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

then i am just iterating over the array looking for spaces

eg

```
char* p = datain;

char accountid[80];
char firstname[80];

// extract the accountid
while(p!='')
{
    accountid = p;
    ++p;
}

++p;

while(p!='')
{
    firstname = p;
    ++p;
}
```

etc....

This method seems a bit crude however my programming skills are not that good so i was wondering if there was a better strategy for transferring  this set of data over a named pipe in Linux.

Thanks

Comment: If you really put `p!='\0'` in there, that's a bug.  I'm guessing you meant `*p!=' '`.

Comment: Also, I assume that `description` can contain spaces, but `accountid`, `firstname`, and `surname` cannot?

Comment: Are there any issue with using pipes from a php script as opposed to bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A pipe (named or not) is a stream of bytes. If you were using the same language on both sides, there might be a better way of sending structured data. In your situation, a manual encoding and decoding, like you're doing, is by far the easiest solution.
- Don't use spaces to separate fields that may contain spaces, such as people's names. Use `:`, like `/etc/passwd`.
- In C, `read` is hard to use, because you have to decide on a buffer size in advance *and* you have to call it in a loop because it may return less than the buffer size on a whim. The functions from `stdio.h` (that operate on a `FILE*` rather than a file descriptor) are easier to use but still require work to handle long lines. If you don't care about portability outside Linux, use `getline`:

  ```
  FILE *pipe = fdopen(fd, "r");
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t line_length;
  getline(&line, &line_length, pipe);
  ```

Then use `strchr` to locate the `:`s in the line. (Don't be tempted to use `strtok`, it's only suitable for whitespace-separated fields that can't be empty.)

Comment: Yeah, using ':' instead of space as a separator is a much better idea, though the main issue is that your separator character should not appear in your data.

Comment: You could also use `strtok()` to parse out the fields.

Comment: @caf: No, `strtok` would treat `::` as a single separator (i.e., you can't have an empty field). This is almost never desirable except when the separators are whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's 2010, you might want to encode your data in JSON or XML, both of which are readily available as libraries for C and almost any other language.

Comment: Whee, lets add megabytes of parsing libraries, complicated interfaces and the inability to easily produce the required data from a shell script in order to move into the future!

Comment: It's not at all difficult to produce JSON data from a shell script. Consuming might be a bit harder, though. BTW, cJSON.o is exactly 40032 bytes on my machine and the interface is not at all complicated.